# Get information on another process on windows from nodejs

Tags: windows, node.js, process

Is there anyway to get the current CPU/memory usage of another process running on the same machine (in windows) via nodejs. I realise this would be trivial on unix by using ps but I need this functionality on windows (its actually to monitor IE8).

Has anyone else faced this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for `Tasklist`. This will give you the pid and memory usage.

Try this:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
ps = spawn('Tasklist');
ps.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
 console.log(data);
});

ps.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('ps stderr: ' + data);
});
```

I'm not sure if tasklist can do cpu usage. However, you can download and install `ProcDump`, then do something similar to the code above.

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
ps = spawn('procdump -ma ' + somePid); // or 'procdump iexplorer'
ps.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
 console.log(data);
});

ps.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('ps stderr: ' + data);
});
```